# How to get administrative level with Google maps Geocode services?

Tags: javascript

I want to get administrative level by *latitude* and *longitude*. My problem is that sometimes I get a blank result.

Here is my code :

```
var latLng = marker.latLng;
$latitude.value = latLng.lat();
$longitude.value = latLng.lng();
var urlgeocode = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + 
latLng.lat()+ "," +latLng.lng() + "&key=AIzaSyB0Yef9tL8vM148wqdMTmYMBEO7qjPtKXE";

$.getJSON(urlgeocode, function(data, textStatus){
    var streetadress= data.results[0].address_components[2].long_name;
    alert(streetadress);
});      
});
```

Here a screenshot of what I want to get :
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.